# Is there any builtin mechanism in rethinkdb to transform array of objects into key value?

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

I want to transform

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "some_name_1", "alias": "alias1"}, {"id": 2, "name": "some_name_2", alias: "alias2"}, {"id": 3, "name": "some_name_3", "alias": "alias3"}]
```

into

```
{"1": {"id": 1, "name": "some_name_1", "alias": "alias1"}, "2": {"id": 2, "name": "some_name_2", alias: "alias2"}, "3": {"id": 3, "name": "some_name_3", "alias": "alias3"}}
```

Comment: Is the dictionary key supposed to be the id or the position in the list?

Comment: it should be id, List Comprehension can be the solution but I want some builtin feature something similar to coerce_to

Comment: @DavidMnatsakanyan Trying to understand more. Any specific reason why you are not fine with *List Comprehension* and looking for something else?

Comment: Just don't what to iterate on the huge list from the client side

Answer (score 0):

You can use *List Comprehension* to achieve this.

**Code:**

```
dict = [{"id": 1, "name": "some_name_1", "alias": "alias1"}, {"id": 2, "name": "some_name_2", "alias": "alias2"}, {"id": 3, "name": "some_name_3", "alias": "alias3"}]
print (*[{str(i+1):x} for i,x in enumerate(dict)])
```

**EDIT:** If Dictionary key should be displayed instead of index,

```
print (*[{x["id"]:x} for x in dict])
```

**Output:**

```
{'1': {'id': 1, 'name': 'some_name_1', 'alias': 'alias1'}} {'2': {'id': 2, 'name': 'some_name_2', 'alias': 'alias2'}} {'3': {'id': 3, 'name': 'some_name_3', 'alias': 'alias3'}}
```

Comment: enumerate is unnecessary since you should be using `x['id']` as the key